# Box - Webhook v2 - 403 Forbidden with Box CLI

Tags: webhooks, http-status-code-403, box-api

I am trying to create a Webhook V2 associated to a folder with the Box CLI (Powershell) but I return this error:

> Unexpected API Response [403 Forbidden | wncdt6fz7hr7j3tk] access_denied_insufficient_permissions - Access denied - insufficient permission

I follow these steps:

1. Create a **Custom App** with **OAuth 2.0 with JWT** Authentication
2. Set **Enterprise** as **Application Access**.
3. **Enable**/Check all **Application Scopes** options.
4. Activate **Perform Actions As Users** and **Generate User Access Token at Advanced Features**.
5. **Generate** a **Public/Private Keypair** and download the JSON to set in my Box CLI.
6. **Authorize** the custom application using the Client ID  at Admin Console.
7. At **Box CLI**, **create the environment** with the JSON configuration downloaded at step 5. Set that environment as default.
8. **Get the Token** to use to create the Webhook with the following command:

   `box tokens:get --user-id $user_number`
9. Create the Webhook:

   `box webhooks:create folder test_lab -T FILE.UPLOADED -a http://test-lab.us-e2.cloudhub.io/lab -t e66kxXI1MyGtXTs7888uy8hutPrreH9R`

When I try to create it, returns the 403 Forbidden error. What can I need to solve the permissions problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set Box Webhook endpoints you need to set the url as `https` and not `http` 
Can you give that a try?